# Process builder respecting validation rule

Tags: process-builder, validation-rule

I have created a picklist called status and that picklist has 4 values: New, Pending, Approved and Rejected. I have added a validation rule called **statusFieldMustBeNew**. So, when a user creates a record then while creating it the status must be new.

If that record is sent for approval then the status will change to pending, approved and rejected (depending upon the condition).

Now my requirement is, when the status field has pending value then I want process builder to post a message to chatter that someone is asking for somekind of approval but processbuilder is respecting that validation rule and I am not able to post a message on Chatter Feed.

so, How do i tell process builder to discard that validation rule? I can attain it by creating a variable and checking the value of it but i want to know if there are other better ways.

The validation rule is:

```
OR(ISPICKVAL( Status__c, 'Pending'),
ISPICKVAL( Status__c, 'Approved'),
ISPICKVAL( Status__c, 'Rejected'),
ISPICKVAL( Status__c, ''))
```

Comment: Please include your validation rule. This site is not a guessing game.

Comment: I have added validation rule.

Comment: From your validation rule and requirement, I guess that the validation rule fires only when the record is created (New) and the status is among Pending, Approved or Reject.

Comment: @Abhishek Daware, yes that is correct.

Comment: If that's the case then @SantanuBoral answer will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your validation rule, every time record is edited or updated, rule is satisfying.

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to fire validation rule during creation and if the status is not `New`. If that is correct the updated rule will be like this:

```
ISNEW() && NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status__c, 'New'))
```